# Significant digit 354 rule from Particle Data Group

Tags: error, measurement-error, reporting

The particle data group (PDG) has a particular rule to round the value of a measurement. You can find the complete description at this [link](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-rpp-intro.pdf) (page 13).

Summarizing:

> ... if the three highest order digits of the error lie between 100
>   and 354, we round to two signiﬁcant digits. If they lie between 355 and 949, we round to one signiﬁcant digit. Finally, if they lie between 950 and 999, we round up to 1000 and keep two signiﬁcant digits. In all cases, the central value is given with a precision that matches that of the error

do you have an idea where this `354` rule come from?

Comment: See this github discussion which has the most justification I've seen for the rule. https://github.com/r-quantities/errors/issues/45#issuecomment-741111094. Maybe I'll try to understand the explanation better and post it as an answer if it makes sense.